# Requesting simple example of how to mix separated audio and video in Android with Mediamuxer

Tags: android, mediamuxer

I would like to write a simple Android application to mux an audio file with the video track from a video file.

Mediamuxer looks like a good solution, and there are some promising-looking examples posted on [googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/MediaMuxerTest.java),  [bigflake](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt), and [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) but I am too much of a newb to understand how to adapt them to my needs. I have been beating my head against this for a couple of weeks now.

Does anyone have a snippet that will do the trick, assuming some arbitrary hard coded paths to the two files on external storage? I think that just getting a good look at something that works will teach me a lot.

Thanks!